# Make a div position relative to another that is static

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a fullscreen site, also responsive, but on smaller screens the elements in the container overflow making it not 100% it varies depending on how many items are in it. Using:

`top:100%;
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:100%`

works, only if the screen is a certain size, on mobile devices using that it doest work, and appears half on the previous container.
Is there a way to position from the bottom of the element rather than top?

http://jsfiddle.net/q8tvwm2k/2/

Update: 
Never minds found a pretty bad but working solution.

Comment: Could you share your HTML so we can try and understand the structure?

Comment: can post all of it but heres a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q8tvwm2k/2/
The white is the container supposed to be below, resize it and see how it varies, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you really want a `position:absolute` to have another div relative to it. You just didn't word the question correctly. `position:relative` sets the point to which its children can be `position:absolute`, which is where you want to use `top` and the like. This is the structure you need to see:

**HTML**

```
<div class='surround'>
  <div class='inside'>
    <div class='outer'>
      <div class='inner'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.surround{
  position:relative;
}
.inside{
  height:100px; width:100px; position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px;
}
.outer{
  height:100px; width:100px; position:relative;
}
.inner{
  position:absolute; top:30px; left:10px;
}
```